# NSDictionary string casting

Tags: iphone, casting, nsdictionary

I've manually written a .plist file with a dictionary.
My problem is that the value for the key "route_id" returned is wrong.
I get a "1" in place of "01".

Here my dict :

```
<dict>
<key>route_desc</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>route_id</key>
<string>01</string>
</dict>
```

Here my code :

```
NSLog(@"%@", [selectedRoute valueForKey:@"route_id"]);
```

Return 1 and not 01;

If anyone can help me to get the right value !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing, but you're messing things up somewhere.  I saved the plist to my desktop and ran:

```
NSDictionary * d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/dave/Desktop/test"];
NSLog(@"%@", d);
NSLog(@"%@", [d valueForKey:@"route_id"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [d objectForKey:@"route_id"]);
```

And got:

```
2011-01-10 14:35:55.437 EmptyFoundation[15631:a0f] {
    "route_desc" = 1;
    "route_id" = 01;
}
2011-01-10 14:35:55.440 EmptyFoundation[15631:a0f] 01
2011-01-10 14:35:55.440 EmptyFoundation[15631:a0f] 01
```